# Защита личной папки пользователя

Tags: windows, безопасность, администрирование, шифрование

Как защитить папку users/Administrator, что бы данные были зашифрованы для любого пользователя. И при этом отключить сброс пароля.
Может есть поточные методики шифрования, где расшифровка происходит при входе пользователя?
P.S.1. Утилиты типа truecrypt не подходят.
P.S.2. Не нужно отправлять меня на рут-код =)

Comment: Установите уже, наконец, линукс:]] В убунте это из коробки имеется:]

Comment: Думаю аргумента, что я asp.net разработчик будет достаточно =)

Comment: @nolka Какой смысл советовать перейти на что-то другое, когда автор спрашивает конкретный вопрос по конкретной ОС (тем более, что добиться желаемого не так уж и сложно).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Не нужно отправлять меня на рут-код

Почему?

[EFS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0)

> Поскольку шифрование/расшифрование файлов происходит с помощью драйвера файловой системы (по сути надстройки над NTFS), оно происходит прозрачно для пользователя и приложений.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю доку в эту сторону.